# Add SKU to minicart above product name

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, mini-cart

I would like to add the product SKU above the product name in the minicart.

[image]

How can I add it?  Do I need to create a copy of one of these files in my theme?
*app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html*
*app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by creating a copy of `app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

in my theme at `app/design/frontend/Holy/mytheme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

and updating the code to include:

```
<strong class="product-item-name">
    <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
    <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_sku}, text: product_sku"></a>
    <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: product_name"></a>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
    <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</strong>
```